# LinQ DataTable Group By

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I have a datatable in vb.net application. the data table is looking like this:

```
State Level City
AL     T     Arlton
AL     T     Brton
AL     T     Rurton
CO     T     Dver
CO     T     Crodo
WA     T     Blain
WA     T     Bwelham
```

I would like to group the state and do a loop
I tried the following but is not working as expected. 
please help

what I tried so far:

```
Dim result = From r In dt Group r By state = r(0) Into Group Select Group
For Each r In result
    Console.WriteLine(r("State"))
Next
```

The output from the loop should be

```
AL
CO
WA
```

Thank you

Comment: Group by Level ? Is that what you want ? Your expected output looks like it is distinct of State/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call GroupBy on a datatable. So you may first convert the datatable to a collection using the `AsEnumerable()` method and then apply your group by

```
Dim itms = dt.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(x) New With {
    Key .City = x.Field(Of String)("City"),
    Key .State = x.Field(Of String)("State"),
    Key .Level = x.Field(Of String)("Level")
})



Dim uniqueStatesgroupedStates = itms.GroupBy(Function(s) s.State, Function(p) p,
                                                                Function(k, v) New With {
    Key .State = k,
    Key .Item = v
})

' IF you want group records based in State

For Each r In uniqueStatesgroupedStates
    Console.WriteLine(r.State)
Next

' IF you want only Unique states from your data table
Dim uniqueStates = itms.[Select](Function(s) s.State).Distinct().ToList()

For Each r In uniqueStates
        Console.WriteLine(r)
Next
```

*Your expected output looks like you want only the unique State names, In that case you simply need to do a Select on State property and call `Distinct()` on that.*

Comment: You don't need to call `.ToList()` in your examples at all.

Comment: @Fabio : Yea. Added it so we can see the results with VS breakpoints to see the data. Removed it now :)

Comment: You can debug lambdas now: [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/11/12/support-for-debugging-lambda-expressions-with-visual-studio-2015/](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/11/12/support-for-debugging-lambda-expressions-with-visual-studio-2015/)

Comment: That is great ! Thanks for sharing the link.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need `distinct` instead of a `group by`, If I understood your question correctly following method will work for you.

```
Dim resultdt As DataTable = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "state")

For Each row In newdt.Rows
    Console.WriteLine(row(0).ToString)
Next
```

[DataView.ToTable Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8ycds2f(v=vs.110).aspx): Creates and returns a new DataTable based on rows in an existing DataView