# Format Data In DataTable With or Without LINQ in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm having a little trouble trying to get some data to format properly.

I'm not sure if LINQ is helpful in this case but below is:

**Expected output**

```
March 14
2:00 PM - 7:00 PM | Registration
5:30 PM - 7:00 PM | Meetup
7:30 PM - 9:00 PM | Dinner
March 15
2:00 PM - 7:00 PM | Registration
5:30 PM - 7:00 PM | Meetup
```

**Current data output**

```
March 14
2:00 PM - 7:00 PM | Registration
March 14
5:30 PM - 7:00 PM | Meetup
March 14
7:30 PM - 9:00 PM | Dinner
March 15
2:00 PM - 7:00 PM | Registration
March 15
6:00 PM - 7:00 PM | Meetup
```

**Code Structure**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.DataSetExtensions

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim sessions = SampleTable()
        Dim ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us")
        For Each session In sessions.AsEnumerable()

            Dim sessionID = session.Item("SessionID")
            Dim sessionDate = CDate(session.Item("SessionStartTime")).ToString("M", ci)
            Dim sessionStart = CDate(session.Item("SessionStartTime")).ToString("t", ci)
            Dim sessionEnd = CDate(session.Item("SessionEndTime")).ToString("t", ci)
            Dim sessionTitle = CStr(session.Item("SessionName"))

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", sessionDate)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} | {2}", sessionStart, sessionEnd, sessionTitle)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Function SampleTable() As DataTable
        Dim table As New DataTable
        With table
            'Add Named Columns
            .Columns.Add("SessionID", GetType(Integer))
            .Columns.Add("SessionStartTime", GetType(Date))
            .Columns.Add("SessionEndTime", GetType(Date))
            .Columns.Add("SessionName", GetType(String))

            'Add 5 Rows of Data to test
            .Rows.Add(1, #03/14/2019 14:00:00#, #03/14/2019 19:00:00#, "Registration")
            .Rows.Add(1, #03/14/2019 17:30:00#, #03/14/2019 19:00:00#, "Meetup")
            .Rows.Add(1, #03/14/2019 19:30:00#, #03/14/2019 21:00:00#, "Dinner")
            .Rows.Add(2, #03/15/2019 14:00:00#, #03/15/2019 19:00:00#, "Registration")
            .Rows.Add(2, #03/15/2019 18:00:00#, #03/15/2019 19:00:00#, "Meetup")
        End With
        Return table
    End Function
End Module
```

I've referenced other SO questions such as [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143387/linq-datatable-group-by) but I'm not sure if LINQ would make the expected output easier to obtain.

Any suggestions are welcomed. I'm trying to possibly add a nested for Each loop and then add a condition if the sessionDate is the same.

****** **UPDATE** *******

I really appreciate the feedback and helpful answers. I'm trying to do one more format change to the data. I have to add a specific SVG Icon to all the events items. The SVG icons are specific to the First, Last, Rest of events.

I'm trying to use the LINQ answer provided but I'm not well versed in using it yet but it does seem very easy to read. For the purposes of this example, A String variable can be used as place holders for the first / rest / last.

I've also added my attempt to try to add the icon but I was not using LINQ.

Below is the *Updated Code* and **Expected Output**

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
March 14
(Start SVG) 2:00 PM - 7:00 PM | Registration
(Body SVG)  5:30 PM - 7:00 PM | Meetup
(End SVG)   7:30 PM - 9:00 PM | Dinner
March 15
(Start SVG) 2:00 PM - 7:00 PM | Registration
(End SVG)   5:30 PM - 7:00 PM | Meetup
```

**Code Structure**

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.DataSetExtensions

Public Module Module1

  Public Sub Main()
    Dim ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us")
    Dim sessionIcon = String.Empty
    'Dim Sessions = SampleTable().AsEnumerable()

    'For Each session In Sessions
    '  If Sessions.Rows.IndexOf(session) = 0 Then
    '    sessionIcon = "<svg>Start Icon</svg>"
    '  ElseIf Sessions.Rows.IndexOf(session) = (Sessions.Rows.Count - 1) Then
    '   sessionIcon = "<svg>End Icon</svg>"
    '  Else
    '    sessionIcon = "<svg>Rest Icon</svg>"
    '  End If
    'Next

    Dim sessions = SampleTable().AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(x) New With {
        Key.SessionDate = x.Field(Of Date)("SessionStartTime").ToString("M", ci),
        Key.SessionStartTime = x.Field(Of Date)("SessionStartTime").ToString("t", ci),
        Key.SessionEndTime = x.Field(Of Date)("SessionEndTime").ToString("t", ci),
        Key.SessionName = x.Field(Of String)("SessionName")
    })

    For Each g In sessions.GroupBy(Function(s) s.SessionDate)
      Console.WriteLine("{0}", g.Key)
      For Each r In g
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} | {2}", r.SessionStartTime, r.SessionEndTime, r.SessionName)
      Next
    Next
End Sub

Public Function SampleTable() As DataTable
  Dim table As New DataTable
    With table
      'Add Named Columns
      .Columns.Add("SessionID", GetType(Integer))
      .Columns.Add("SessionStartTime", GetType(Date))
      .Columns.Add("SessionEndTime", GetType(Date))
      .Columns.Add("SessionName", GetType(String))

    'Add 5 Rows of Data to test
    .Rows.Add(1, #03/14/2019 14:00:00#, #03/14/2019 19:00:00#, "Registration")
      .Rows.Add(1, #03/14/2019 17:30:00#, #03/14/2019 19:00:00#, "Meetup")
      .Rows.Add(1, #03/14/2019 19:30:00#, #03/14/2019 21:00:00#, "Dinner")
      .Rows.Add(2, #03/15/2019 14:00:00#, #03/15/2019 19:00:00#, "Registration")
      .Rows.Add(2, #03/15/2019 18:00:00#, #03/15/2019 19:00:00#, "Meetup")
    End With
  Return table
End Function
End Module
```

Comment: If there are additional questions, it is better to do it before marking as resolved.
If it has been settled, there is a high possibility that everyone will not notice the question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't need the extra formatting so the question remains resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using LINQ, like this

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us")

    Dim sessions = SampleTable().AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(x) New With {
        Key .SessionDate = x.Field(Of Date)("SessionStartTime").ToString("M", ci),
        Key .SessionStartTime = x.Field(Of Date)("SessionStartTime").ToString("t", ci),
        Key .SessionEndTime = x.Field(Of Date)("SessionEndTime").ToString("t", ci),
        Key .SessionName = x.Field(Of String)("SessionName")
    })

    For Each g In sessions.GroupBy(Function(s) s.SessionDate)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", g.Key)
        For Each r In g
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} | {2}", r.SessionStartTime, r.SessionEndTime, r.SessionName)
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Addition

Basically it is not wrong with your way of thinking.
The position to add that code is slightly different.
Because you want to process each row grouped by date
It must be done in that loop.

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us")

    Dim sessions = SampleTable().AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(x) New With {
    Key .SessionDate = x.Field(Of Date)("SessionStartTime").ToString("M", ci),
    Key .SessionStartTime = x.Field(Of Date)("SessionStartTime").ToString("t", ci),
    Key .SessionEndTime = x.Field(Of Date)("SessionEndTime").ToString("t", ci),
    Key .SessionName = x.Field(Of String)("SessionName")
})

    For Each g In sessions.GroupBy(Function(s) s.SessionDate)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", g.Key)
        For Each r In g
            Dim sessionIcon As String
            If r.Equals(g.First) Then
                sessionIcon = "<svg>Start Icon</svg>"
            ElseIf r.Equals(g.Last) Then
                sessionIcon = "<svg>End Icon</svg>"
            Else
                sessionIcon = "<svg>Body Icon</svg>"
            End If
            Console.WriteLine("{3} {0} - {1} | {2}", r.SessionStartTime, r.SessionEndTime, r.SessionName, sessionIcon)
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not looking for something fancy, this will probably accomplish the end result:

```
Dim sessions = SampleTable()
Dim ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us")
Dim dateList As New List(Of String)
For Each session In sessions.AsEnumerable()

    Dim sessionID = session.Item("SessionID")
    Dim sessionDate = CDate(session.Item("SessionStartTime")).ToString("M", ci)
    Dim sessionStart = CDate(session.Item("SessionStartTime")).ToString("t", ci)
    Dim sessionEnd = CDate(session.Item("SessionEndTime")).ToString("t", ci)
    Dim sessionTitle = CStr(session.Item("SessionName"))

    If Not dateList.Contains(sessionDate) Then
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", sessionDate)
        dateList.Add(sessionDate)
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} | {2}", sessionStart, sessionEnd, sessionTitle)
Next
```

Comment: I like this answer as well. However, the data would need to be provided in order prior to being looped through as it doesn't account for dates out of order. This is a minor issue as I'm using a Stored Procedure to populate the data and it is just as easy to do a SORT BY Date on the back end.

Answer (score 0):

I added a complication that allows the events to be entered in any order then sorted into a DataView.

```
Sub Main()

        Dim sessions = SampleTable()
        Dim SortedView As New DataView(sessions)
        SortedView.Sort = "SessionStartTime"
        Dim ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us")
        Dim row As DataRowView = SortedView(0)
        Dim currentDate As String = #1/1/1950#.ToString("YYYY-MM-dd") 'CDate(row("SessionStartTime")).Date

        For Each session As DataRowView In SortedView
            If currentDate <> CDate(session.Item("SessionStartTime")).ToString("YYYY-MM-dd") Then

                Dim sessionDate = CDate(session.Item("SessionStartTime")).ToString("M", ci)

                Console.WriteLine("{0}", sessionDate)
                currentDate = CDate(session.Item("SessionStartTime")).ToString("YYYY-MM-dd")
            End If
            Dim sessionID = session.Item("SessionID")
                Dim sessionStart = CDate(session.Item("SessionStartTime")).ToString("t", ci)
                Dim sessionEnd = CDate(session.Item("SessionEndTime")).ToString("t", ci)
                Dim sessionTitle = CStr(session.Item("SessionName"))
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} | {2}", sessionStart, sessionEnd, sessionTitle)

        Next
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub
    Public Function SampleTable() As DataTable
        Dim table As New DataTable
        With table
            'Add Named Columns
            .Columns.Add("SessionID", GetType(Integer))
            .Columns.Add("SessionStartTime", GetType(Date))
            .Columns.Add("SessionEndTime", GetType(Date))
            .Columns.Add("SessionName", GetType(String))
            .Rows.Add(2, #03/15/2019 18:00:00#, #03/15/2019 19:00:00#, "Meetup")
            'Add 5 Rows of Data to test
            'Notice that the Events do not have to added in order
            .Rows.Add(2, #03/15/2019 18:00:00#, #03/15/2019 19:00:00#, "Meetup")
            .Rows.Add(1, #03/14/2019 14:00:00#, #03/14/2019 19:00:00#, "Registration")
            .Rows.Add(1, #03/14/2019 17:30:00#, #03/14/2019 19:00:00#, "Meetup")
            .Rows.Add(1, #03/14/2019 19:30:00#, #03/14/2019 21:00:00#, "Dinner")
            .Rows.Add(2, #03/15/2019 14:00:00#, #03/15/2019 19:00:00#, "Registration")

        End With
        Return table
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Readable LINQ with help of presenter class

```
Public Class Session
    Private ReadOnly _ci As CultureInfo
    Public ReadOnly Name As String
    Public ReadOnly StartTime As Date
    Public ReadOnly EndTime As Date

    Public Sub New(row As DataRow, CultureInfo ci)
        _ci= ci
        Name = row.Field(Of String)("SessionName")
        StartTime = row.Field(Of Date)("SessionStartTime")
        EndTime = row.Field(Of Date)("SessionEndTime")
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{StartTime.ToString("t", ci)} - {EndTime.ToString("t", ci)} | {Name}"
    End Function
End Class

' Format rows with the key row
Dim sessions = SampleTable()
Dim ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us")
var output = 
    sessions.AsEnumerable().
            Select(Function(row) New Session(row, ci)).
            GroupBy(Function(session) session.StartTime.Date).
            Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                      Function(builder, day)
                        builder.AppendLine(day.Key.ToString("M", ci))
                        day.Aggregate(builder, Function(b, session) b.AppendLine(session))
                        Return builder
                      End Function).
            ToString()    

Console.WriteLine(output)
```